# Sprite-Kit: Node won't move left

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

i have a ball with a flat terrain, however i am trying to move the ball according to the user's `touch` location, so when the user taps any where on the screen, i move my ball to the touch's `X` position

My code:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

   for touch in touches {

            if (ball?.hasActions())! {
                ball?.removeAllActions()
            }
            let moveBY = SKAction.moveBy(x: touch.location(in: view).x, y: 70, duration: 1)
            self.ball?.run(moveBY)
    }
}
```

however, when the user taps on the screen, the ball moves accordingly, but when it comes to a second tap, the ball won't move according to the touch's `X`

Answer (score 1):

You are using [moveBy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417722-moveby) when you should be using [moveTo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417768-moveto).

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
 func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {

    if ball.hasActions() {
        ball.removeAllActions()
    }

    let moveBY = SKAction.moveBy(x: pos.x, y: 70, duration: 1)
    self.ball.run(moveBY)
}
```

I changed the function

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: Well the touchDown function is called, if the screen is tapped. So the code tests if there already is an action, and stops this current running action. Then i just add another action, that runs until it finished or is quitted.